# django media path problem

Tags: python, django

I am having some problems in figuring out the media path problem in django. In the settings.py file, I have ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'. So certain css and js files like forms.css,RelatedObjectLookup.js files are having the path like this

/media/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookup.js 
and /media/admin/css/forms.css.

There is not folder in my project like /media/admin. However when I run the server using manage.py script and browse the page, the above css and js files are being loaded. I can see that the files forms.css and RelatedObjectLookup.js are in the django itself. However, I am confused about the path in the django itself. It is something like this

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/js/calendar.js

So, I am confused, how are the files being fetched. In the server log I can see the GET request for other files but not for these files(forms.css and RelatedObjectLookup.js)

I have the following in myserver request log after running manage.py.

```
[23/Aug/2011 02:20:36] "GET /media/js/DateTimeShortcuts.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Aug/2011 02:20:36] "GET /media/js/custom/new_appointment_new.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Aug/2011 02:20:36] "GET /media/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Aug/2011 02:20:36] "GET /media/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Aug/2011 02:20:36] "GET /media/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

As you can there is no request for the forms.css and RelatedObjectLookup.js files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be there are no requests for them because they are saved in your browser's cache? Try force-refreshing, or using some tool such as HttpFox.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [AdminMediaHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L163) that is used by the [runserver command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L143). As you can see, the AdminMediaHandler doesn't log anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is an URL path. If you are running the server with `runserver`, Django's server takes care of resolving requests to `http://localhost/media/admin/whatever.js` and serving up the admin's static files. It doesn't print GET requests for those files to the console.

Howewver, if you're not running with `runserver`, then you have to make sure that the path that `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` specifies does actually serve up the static files for the admin. For instance, in one of our sites, our `STATIC_URL` is `http://static.oursite.com/` and our `STATIC_ROOT` is `/srv/django-static/oursite/`. The `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is set to `http://static.oursite.com/admin/`. When we run `python manage.py collecstatic`, it takes all the static files and puts them in the `STATIC_ROOT`. It also makes a folder called `admin` in the `STATIC_ROOT` and puts all the admin's files there. A different server is responsible for serving stuff on `http://static.oursite.com/` and it simply serves up the `STATIC_ROOT` folder, which also has the `admin` folder in it. That way, the normal static files get resolved, as well as those for the admin.